# E-commerce web site with Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, e-commerce

I need to create a `Ecommerce` web site with `Java EE`. So any one has a source code, tutorial any things can help.

Comment: Have you googled ? what have you come up with ?

Comment: Other people have asked about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce+java

Comment: I advise that you don't. Nothing good will come out of "I want to create X, tell me how". Do it only if it's for educational purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Well question is not clear and you need to answer a lot of questions before some one can give you a real inputs.

In short Ecommerce can have

1. B2C Application
2. B2B Application
3. MultiChannel

and many more and what kind of application you are planning to have will fetch answers, there are lots lots of Open-source E-Commerce solutions there and here are few of them.

1. Apache Offbiz
2. Broadleafe
3. KonaKart
4. Shopizer

and there are more, all you need to download them see which best fit in your needs to start working with them.Also be sure that no one will provide you 100% what you need and all those framework comes with a lots of extension points and only thing you need to use those extensions to create custom functionalists.

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Petstore 2.0](http://java.sun.com/developer/releases/petstore/) could be a start.